# Category Members API - Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I had a script which used the sort keys from this API call. Previously it returned values in such a fashion:

```
ns = 876bcb5a0a63ac522ceb8c54647bf59b+\43168
title = Album:Bits And Blood (EP)
sortkey = CAT001
```

But now, the sortkey does not return the value as it used to. Any ideas?

```
ns= 876bcb5a0a63ac522ceb8c54647bf59b+\43168
title=Album:Bits And Blood (EP)
sortkey=383038312d3036310a4249545320414e4420424c4f4f442028455029
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this announcement](http://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/mediawiki-api/2011-April/002244.html) to the mediawiki-api mailing list. In short, for internationalized sorting they changed the sortkey value stored in the database to a binary representation, and so in the API they changed it to output it as hex-encoded to not break clients expecting text rather than binary content.

The human-readable value is available as `sortkeyprefix`.